# Overwrite inherited struct method

Tags: go, methods, struct, overwrite

What I am trying to do is overwrite the String() method, which I am able to do, but I like to also inherit the other mail.Address fields.

Following code lets me overwrite the String() method, however I can't even Access the other methods. I am thinking it may have to do with String being an interface, or the Address struct also having a field name called Address. I can access the mail.Address.Name field with  ad.Name but have to use ad.Address.Address for the mail.Address.Address field.
So what am I not getting here?
[Go Play](https://go.dev/play/p/nQg8fzotzOy)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/mail"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var err error
    var ad = new(EAddress)
    //ad, err = ad.ParseAddress("<alice@example.com>")
    ad.Address, err = ad.Address.ParseAddress("<alice@example.com>")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(ad.Name, ad.Address.Address)
    fmt.Println(ad.String())
}

type EAddress struct {
    *mail.Address
}

func (a EAddress) ParseAddress(p string) (*mail.Address, error) {
    return mail.ParseAddress(p)
}

func (a *EAddress) String() string {
    if a == nil || a.Address.Address == "" {
        return ""
    }
    b := &strings.Builder{}
    if a.Name == "" {
        a.Name = strings.Title(strings.Split(a.Address.Address, "@")[0])
    }
    b.WriteString(a.Name)
    b.WriteRune(' ')
    b.WriteRune('<')
    b.WriteString(a.Address.Address)
    b.WriteRune('>')
    return b.String()
}
```

Comment: There's NO inheritance in Go. `*mail.Address` is an **embedded** field of `EAddress`. An embedded type's members (fields and methods) are "promoted" to the embedding struct. A "promoted" member can be accessed directly by the embedding struct instead of having to go through the embedded field, that's all that "promoted" means. No inheritance. No type extensions. Plain old composition.

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go and thus you cannot overwrite method. Embedding is not inheritance and you cannot (actually nobody can) model inhertiance. Also: Duplicate.

Comment: Also, an embedded field's name is automatically set to the type's unqualified name. So the `*mail.Address` embedded field's name is `Address`. You can access the `Name` field either with `ad.Address.Name` or `ad.Name` (thanks to promotion). However if the embedded type has a member whose name matches the unqualified name of the embedded type then you have to use the full selector `ad.Address.Address` since `ad.Address` evaluates to the value of the embedded field, i.e. `*mail.Address`.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it happens because of ambiguous access to `ad.Address`. Golang treats `ad.Address` as access to the anonymous field `*mail.Address` in the `EAddress` struct, but you probably treat `ad.Address` as an inherited string field `Address` from embedded in `EAddress` type `*mail.Address`.